# Which design pattern to learn first for javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to learn a pattern / process for making and organising proper javascript applications. I am beginning to use OOP to simplify sections of my code, but the code is still messy so I need a process to build bigger things effectively. Should I be thinking about MVC, namespaces or libraries? Not sure if I want to choose a framework yet but any advice/suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: oops sorry about that - i'll see if i can delete this question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is the best Javascript framework and you can start looking on it following the official **[website](http://jquery.com/)**.

Following **[this blog](http://www.jquery4u.com/)** you can find many tutorials and lessons as well.

Then if you are interested in **MVC** pattern to use with Javascript I suggest **[Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)**.

Comment: thanks for the backbone suggestion! i've already been using jquery a lot- this looks like a great option to structure larger projects so i'll look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is all you need :

- http://dochub.io/#javascript/
- http://dochub.io/#jquery/

Answer (score 0):

the basic knowledge of JavaScript is good to learn jquery

since the jquery is the library made in JavaScript you can manipulate and understand jquery  better

Comment: Agreed. I'd particularly recommend reading [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) to anyone who hasn't already

Comment: - i already know a lot of jquery - im looking for an organisation/building process for more advanced projects